# Can I invoke routed WPF command from WinForm control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

In windows form I have a reference to WPF wrapper which wraps WinForm control. I would like to handle events in WinForm control as usual and then invoke apropriate routed commands from WPF wrapper. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as your target for the command is the window host.